# Android Import correct Class for Item & ItemView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

i want to use [Customizing Android ListView Rows by Subclassing](http://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/customizing-android-listview-rows-subclassing/) in my application but after wending that way i get an error to Import correct class for `Item` & `ItemView` my app support old version of android and i'm using `android.support` for any class.

Notify for import `Item`:
[image]

Notify for import `ItemView`:
[image]

introducing class for inport not correct and i get an error such as `setItem`.

How to resolve this problem and can be import correct class?

ItemAdapter class:

```
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import ir.tsms.wsdl.ReceiveFields;

public class ItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ReceiveFields> {

    public ItemAdapter(Context c, List<ReceiveFields> items) {
        super(c, 0, items);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ItemView itemView = (ItemView)convertView;
        if (null == itemView)
            itemView = ItemView.inflate(parent);
        itemView.setItem(getItem(position));
        return itemView;
    }

}
```

Fragment:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ArrayList<ReceiveFields> items = new ArrayList<ReceiveFields>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        String url = String.format("http://www.google.com/image/%d.png", i);
        String title = String.format("Item %d", i);
        String description = String.format("Description of Item %d", i);
        Item item = new Item(url, title, description);
        items.add(item);
    }

    setListAdapter(new ItemAdapter(getActivity(), items));

    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be importing anything for those classes. You should be defining them, just like in the example you've linked.

Answer (score 0):

As Mike M says you should be defining the Item and ItemView classes rather then trying to import them. Hence, and this is from your link, you should have two classes. ItemView looks kind of like:

```
public class ItemView extends RelativeLayout {
    private TextView mTitleTextView;
    private TextView mDescriptionTextView;
    private ImageView mImageView;

    public ItemView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_view_children, this, true);
        setupChildren();
    }

    public static ItemView inflate(ViewGroup parent) {
         ItemView itemView = (ItemView)LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item_view, parent, false);
         return itemView
    }

    private void setupChildren() {
         mTitleTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.item_titleTextView);
         mDescriptionTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.item_descriptionTextView);
         mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.item_imageView);
    }

    public void setItem(Item item) {
         mTitleTextView.setText(item.getTitle());
         mDescriptionTextView.setText(item.getDescription());
         // TODO: set up image URL
    }
}
```

And then you would also need an Item class and to set up your layout files. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The sample code for the tutorial is on github. Here are the key classes I used:

https://github.com/bignerdranch/android-listview-custom-view/tree/master/ListItemViewDemo/src/com/bignerdranch/android/listitemviewdemo

"Item" and "ItemView" are just the names I chose; you might want to use something more specific to your application's domain.

Glad you like the pattern!